# Android Java Runnable, How do I open another activity when a condition in the runnable is met?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

First off, I'm virtually completely new to android development.

I've been trying to build a simple game where the player has to perfrom an action before the time runs out (represented with a progressbar). If the player performs the act succesfully, he or she gains more time.

The draining of the progressbar is done with an runnable (see below)

```
final ProgressBar time = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.time_left);   
final Runnable timer = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            time.setProgress(time.getProgress() - 4);
            int ProgressRemaining = time.getProgress();
            if (ProgressRemaining == 0) {
                h.removeCallbacks(null);
                YouLose();
            }
            h.postDelayed(this, 10);
        }
    };
```

(Code in between)

```
public void YouLose() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, youLose.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

With every cycle the runnable checks if the progressbar hits zero. The problem is that I want the application to start a new activity once the player has reached that point, I learned the hard way that starting a new activity this way causes huge lag and/or crashes.

Can someone help me how I can start a new activity once the player runs out of time? (I know I've done some dumb shit, don't be afraid to tell me how something like this should really be done.)

Thank you in advance

Comment: huge lag? why? that's the right way to go another activity

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a program called `EventBus`. https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

When ProgressRemaining is 0 you can call a simple and quick EventBus method like so;

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(progressRemaining);
```

...and in your Activity or base Activity have a simple receive method like so;

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void onEventMainThread(int progressRemaining){
    youLose();
}
```

Doing this allows you to bridge the gap between your background and foreground thread.

There is a small amount of additional set up required in your Application class but that's all documented on their GitHub page. I would also recommend that you create an empty event class called something like `ProgressReachedZeroEvent` and pass that through your `EventBus` post instead of passing back an int so you have more control over which event reads your post (in-case you have additional onEvent's in your application in the future.

Also, you should start off your methods and variables with a lower case letter. Only class names should start off with an upper-case.

**EDIT**: From re-reading your question it seems that you are not trying to start an `Activity` from the background thread. So ignore what I've answered. It seems that you are doing everything perfectly fine for starting a new `Activity` can you elaborate on what you are experiencing? The lag would probably be from something else, not the way you're starting the next `Activity`. If you are getting a crash every time. Make sure you have declared your new `Activity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Posting your crash report will help resolve your problem faster.

I would recommend doing this instead:

```
Timer timer;

private void setup() {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
                // your code goes here
            );
        }

    },0,1000);  // update every second
}
```

...and to stop the `Timer`:

```
if (timer != null) {
     timer.cancel();
     timer = null;
 }
```

Comment: The main problem I'm experiencing is that whenever I call for a new activity from within the runnable, it starts te take a very long time and in the CPU monitor I see Giant spikes. However, when I call YouLose() when the player does the taak incorrectly (regardless of the time) there is absolutely no lag and everything's fine. SO I already know it is not because of the shutting down of the runnable or anything. Personally I think the problem lies within the fact that it is somehow trying to continuessly de start the new activity.

Comment: Maybe you're calling it multiple times? Can you paste more of your code into your question, and maybe a crash log if you're still getting one?

Comment: It never really crashes (very rarely). It just lags for a couple of seconds. When I read the CPU state of my Nexus, it says that the app is consuming 40 to 60% of its capacity, just to run my app

Comment: SO I think that there is something wrong with the h.removecallbacks(null)